# Failed to compile 0.9.8zg on Windows when using no-ssl2 and no-ssl3

Tags: visual-studio, openssl

I am trying to compile OpenSSL 0.9.8zg on Windows 7 (32-bit) using Visual Studio 2012 express, and ActivePerl.  When I try to compile without any options:

1. "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"
2. Perl Configure VC-WIN32 --prefix=c:\openssl-0.9.8zg-bin\
3. ms\do_ms
4. nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak

The DLL will compile, and I can use it with my project.  However, if I try to compile OpenSSL with no-ssl2 or no-ssl3 or both, the it fails during the make.  My actual configure line looks like:

Perl Configure no-ssl2 no-ssl3 VC-WIN32 --prefix=c:\openssl-0.9.8zg-bin\

The error messages I receive are:

```
link /nologo /subsystem:console /opt:ref /dll /out:out32dll\ssleay32.dll
  /def:ms/SSLEAY32.def @C:\Users\jtromble\AppData\Local\Temp\nm2586.tmp
SSLEAY32.def : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol SSLv23_client_method
SSLEAY32.def : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol SSLv23_method
SSLEAY32.def : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol SSLv23_server_method
SSLEAY32.def : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol SSLv2_client_method
SSLEAY32.def : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol SSLv2_method
SSLEAY32.def : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol SSLv2_server_method
SSLEAY32.def : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol SSLv3_client_method
SSLEAY32.def : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol SSLv3_method
SSLEAY32.def : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol SSLv3_server_method
out32dll\ssleay32.lib : fatal error LNK1120: 9 unresolved externals
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio        11.0\VC\BIN\link.EXE"' : return code '0x460'
```

I don't really understand why it would try to link object files for these if I'm calling no-ssl2 no-ssl3 in the build option.  From the looks of the makefile, it's specifying the options:

```
CC= cl
CFLAG= -DOPENSSL_THREADS  -DDSO_WIN32
DEPFLAG= -DOPENSSL_NO_CAMELLIA -DOPENSSL_NO_CAPIENG -DOPENSSL_NO_CMS -    DOPENSSL_NO_GMP -DOPENSSL_NO_JPAKE -DOPENSSL_NO_MDC2 -DOPENSSL_NO_RC5 -DOPENSSL_NO_RFC3779 -DOPENSSL_NO_SEED -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL2 -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL3
PEX_LIBS=
EX_LIBS=
EXE_EXT=
ARFLAGS=
AR= ar $(ARFLAGS) r
ARD=ar $(ARFLAGS) d
RANLIB= true
PERL= perl
TAR= tar
TARFLAGS= --no-recursion --record-size=10240
```

I would appreciate any help/guidance anyone can provide.

Comment: Did you remove all the folders (generated from your first build) and unpack the archive again, before configuring with `no-ssl2 no-ssl3`?

Comment: This looks like a bug in the Windows gear for 0.9.8. But I seem to recall doing the same with 1.0.1 last year with no problems. Considering [0.9.8 is going to be EOL](https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2014/12/23/the-new-release-strategy/) in six months, can you upgrade to 1.0..2?

Comment: Thanks. I did try cleaning out the folders as suggested by CristiFati but that did not change the outcome.  When I looked through the mkdef.pl script, I did not notice any place where it would parse those options to build the .def files, which makes me wonder if there are other problems in this version as jww suggests (bug).  I'm looking into using a new version of OpenSSL with the project I'm building.